# why is broadcom wireless so difficult with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

This is the second laptop I've tried to convert to Linux and the only thing that gives me trouble is the wireless.

Comment: Sorry but what is your problem, edit your question adding relevant information about the problems involving your wireless setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and this is what I did:

The best way to fix this is to first use a wired connection. Plug in an ethernet cable and do this:

1. Open a terminal and type the following:

   $ sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common
2. Find out what type of card you have. Just type in:

   $ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4

If you get BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4313, BCM4321, BCM4322, BCM43224, BCM43225, **BCM43227, or **BCM43228...

1. Type this in a terminal:

   $ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

If you get BCM4306/3, BCM4311, BCM4312, BCM4318, or BCM4320...

1. Type in this:

   $ sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter

   $ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer (if wanted)

   $ sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl (some things will give errors, don't worry)

   $ sudo modprobe b43

   $ sudo modprobe ndiswrapper

You should be able to now get ndiswrapper working, and I think that's about it. You can configure like normal from there...

Good luck ^-^